# Trees of <ul> elements and on-click behaviour

Tags: javascript, html, chromium, dom-events

We have some internal code that displays trees of data in HTML form using nested `<ul>` elements. There's some jQuery UI code that toggles subtree visibility using the `slideToggle()` method and we override the bullet point characters with little plus and minus boxes. The idea is that you click on the little plus and the relevant subtree expands nicely. To get the boxes rendered in the right place, we use `list-style-position: inside`.

With the latest version of Chromium (version 76.0.3809.62-1), the Javascript code no longer works properly. Clicking on the bullet point actually passes the event to the enclosing `<ul>` (rather than the list item itself). I've added a minimal example showing the behaviour below, although you'll need a recent Chrome/Chromium to see it. Instead of toggling subtrees, this toggles whether the list item is shown in red. With the latest version of Chromium,

My question is whether there's a right way to catch these click events. In particular, I'd like to use the layout shown, but I want to make sure that clicking on the bullet point causes the bullet point's item to toggle (not the surrounding tree). Are we just doing this the wrong way? And, if so, how should we be doing it?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>List item test</title>
    <style>
      .red { color: red; }
      ul { list-style-position: inside; }
      ul ul li { background-color: lightgrey; }
    </style>
    <script>
      function on_click (event) {
          tgt = event.target;

          // tgt might be a child of the <li> element. Walk up until
          // we find one. Give up early if we hit a <ul>.
          while (tgt.tagName != "LI") {
              tgt = tgt.parentElement
              if (tgt === null) {
                  return;
              }
          }

          tgt.classList.toggle("red");
          event.stopPropagation();
      }

      window.onload = function() {
          for (ul of document.querySelectorAll("ul")) {
              ul.addEventListener('click', on_click);
          }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <ul>
          <li>AAA</li>
          <li class="red">BBB</li>
          <li>CCC</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do you install click handlers on every UL rather than just on the root UL ?

Comment: Honestly, because that's how the code I was modifying worked. You're right though: installing on just the root would be better. Unfortunately, that doesn't make any difference to the click target problem I was having :-(

Comment: Well, I just tried with Version 77.0.3840.0 (Official Build) (32-bit) and it works fine - watch the screencast (https://vimeo.com/349917718)

Comment: @IVOGELOV: Thank you very much for the reply. I've just watched the vimeo video and I don't think you tried clicking on the "o" bullets (as opposed to the text). Does that work for you as well? I will try downloading various chromium/chrome versions in the next couple of days and narrow down exactly what versions I'm seeing problems with.

Comment: You are right - there is something strange with v77 when I am clicking on or very close to the bullet points. Definitely a regression in Chromium as it works perfectly fine in v75.

Comment: Hmm. Reported as https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=988414

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Chromium bug, which looks like it will be fixed in the next stable release. See https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=988414 for all the details.